# Android my code rxjava works slowly

Tags: android, rx-java, intentservice

In my application there is a method of obtaining data through the API. It is carried out in the IntentService. The received data is written to the database. I rewrote this method with the help of the rxjava, but the execution time has greatly increased.
Here is my code in IntentService

```
Call<List<DocLine>> DocLineResult = mApi.getDocLine(UserID, LastUserDate);
Response<List<DocLine>> responseDocLine = DocLineResult.execute();
if (responseDocLine.isSuccessful()) {
    List<DocLine> docLines = responseDocLine.body();
    if (docLines != null) {
        for (DocLine item : docLines) {
            mContents = new ContentValues();
            //filling mContents from item
            dbBase.insertWithOnConflict(dbTabName, null, mContents, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        }
        Log.d(AppGlobal.LOG_TAG, dbTabName + " => " + docLines.size());
    }
}
else {
    if (responseDocHead.raw() != null && responseDocHead.raw().code() == 404) {
        throw new Exception(getString(R.string.error_null_user));
    else
        throw new Exception("Error");
    }
}
```

Here is my code rxjava

```
Observable oDocLine = apiService.getDocLine(userId, lastSyncDate)
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .flatMap(docLine -> Observable.create(subscriber -> {workDB.save(docLine, null); subscriber.onCompleted();})
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()));
```

Comment: please don't mix pascalcase and camelcase for variable naming. It makes your code impossible to read

Comment: it's constructive, try to follow java naming conventions

Comment: Can you post your actual code, after fixing the compiler warnings and errors? Also, you can add logging statements at each step using `.doOnNext( value -> logger.debug("step 1 " + value) )`. This will help narrow down what is taking so long.

Comment: It's slow because you don't begin/commit transaction so every insert call is a new transaction

Answer (score 0):

You second flatmap seems to serve no useful purpose except to add a side-effect.

```
Observable oDocLine = apiService.getDocLine(userId, lastSyncDate)
            .flatMap(Observable::from)            
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(docLine -> workDB.save(docLine, null));
```

Should be hopefully more efficient.